# Text field to launch file upload dialog: how to get the filename?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a text field that once clicked, opens a file upload dialog. I did this by creating a second input tag with visibility: hidden.

I want the file chosen in the dialog to then show up in the text field, but haven't been able to get it to work. I haven't even been able to get the file name yet via jQuery. What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```js
$('#import-file-text-field').click(function(){
  $("#import-file-text-field-hidden").trigger("click");
  // $("#import-file-text-field-hidden").show();
  let filename = $('#import-file-text-field-hidden').val();
  var f  = $('input[type=file]').val();
  console.log("File chosen for upload:", filename, f)
});
```

```css
body { 
 background-color: #aaa;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 color: #aaa;
}  

.import_list_table {
  width: 380px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.import_list_table td {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.gray-button {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 6px 12px 10px 12px;
  height: 33px;
  width: 162px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0px 10px 15px 0px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.green-button {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #b3d450;
  padding: 6px 12px 10px 12px;
  height: 33px;
  width: 162px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0px 10px 15px 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gray-button:hover, .green-button:hover{
  opacity: .60;
  color: #000;
}

.gray-button:active, .green-button:active{
  opacity: 1.0;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.import-blue-box {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #59a2c8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.import-blue-box .fa-file-image {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#import-file-text-field{
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 260px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<table class="import_list_table" border=0>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"><center><h4>Upload a file to import your contact list.</h4></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="import-blue-box">
      <i class="far fa-file-image fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
  </td>
<td><br>
  <input type="text" id="import-file-text-field" placeholder="No file chosen">
  <input id="import-file-text-field-hidden" type="file" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
  <br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
  <div>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="gray-button pull-left" id="import_cancel_button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="green-button pull-right" id="import_list_button" data-dismiss="modal">Import List</button>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
          
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: because you are reading it before the user selects the file. You need the change event on the file input....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for the `change` event and get the file input value or `files` prop.
 Here's a simplified version:

```js
var $name = $("#name"),
    $file = $("#file");

$name.on("click", function(){
  $file.trigger("click");
});

$file.on("change", function(e) {
   var data = $file.prop('files')[0];
   
   if(!data) return;
   data.fakepath = $file.val();
   $name.val( data.name );
   console.log( data );
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="No file chosen">
<input id="file" type="file" hidden>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

In plain JS it would look like:

```js
const EL = s => document.querySelector(s),
      EL_name = EL('#name'),
      EL_file = EL('#file');

EL_name.addEventListener("click", () => EL_file.click() );

EL_file.addEventListener("change", () => {
   let data = EL_file.files[0];
   
   if(!data) return;
   data.fakepath = EL_file.value;
   EL_name.value = data.name;
   console.log( data );
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="No file chosen">
<input id="file" type="file" hidden>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and provided more information I can use. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your click eventhandler for `input type=text` can be shortened to:

```
$('#import-file-text-field').click(function(){
  $("#import-file-text-field-hidden").trigger("click");
});
```

Now add an eventlistener to the hidden `input=file` like this:

```
$("#import-file-text-field-hidden").on('change', function()
{
  let filename = $('#import-file-text-field-hidden').val();
  var f  = $('input[type=file]').val();
  console.log("File chosen for upload:", filename, f)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for using my existing code in your answer. I tried your solution, but it didn't work until I changed `.on('input',` to `.on('change',`.